# Firebase Notifications using node.js

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working with Firebase notifications using node.js.
After compile, when I'm sending request to other user of app (request makes notification), firebase log shows error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'receiver_id' of undefined
>       at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:12:36)
>       at Object. (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
>       at next (native)
>       at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
>       at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
>       at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
>       at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:700:26
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Index.js code:

```
'use strict'


const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require ('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification = 
functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{receiver_id}/{notification_id}')
    .onWrite(event => 
    {
        const receiver_id = event.params.receiver_id;

        const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

        console.log('We have a notification to send to :', receiver_id);

        if(!event.data.val())
        {
            return console.log('A notification has been deleted from the database: ', notification_id);
        }

        const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${receiver_id}/device_token`).once('value');

        return deviceToken.then(result => 
        {
            const token_id = result.val();

            const payload = 
            {
                notification: 
                {
                    title: "Friend Request",
                    body: "you have received a new friend request",
                    icon: "default"
                }
            };

            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload)
                        .then(response =>
                        {
                            console.log('This was the notification feature.');
                        });
        });
    });
```

I have read about new APIs on site:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

I think I must change event to context, but I don't know how.
Is anybody know what's the issue?
Thank's for any Help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Firebase documentation on the new `data` and `context`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#event_parameter_split_into_data_and_context) shows where the `params` now live:

> The `context` parameter provides information about the function's execution. Identical across asynchronous functions types, context contains the fields `eventId`, `timestamp`, `eventType`, `resource`, and **`params`**.

So to get rid of that error, you'll need to change the first bit of your function to:

```
exports.sendNotification = 
functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{receiver_id}/{notification_id}')
    .onWrite((data, context) => 
    {
        const receiver_id = context.params.receiver_id;

        const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

        ...
```

There are more, similar changes that you'll need to make. If you're having a hard time making those yourself, I recommend you check back in with where you got the code from.

Comment: Okay, it solve this error and give me another. As You told, i must to change some commands. However thank You for reply. It's really helpful

Comment: Thank's for this sample. Something strange. I've clicked yet, but I haven't enought reputation points to display this operation.