# Not receiving notifications with firebase functions

Tags: javascript, java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have been trying to implement `Cloud Messaging` for my app so that every user of the app would receive notification automatically when a new child is added to the `Realtime Database.`

In my `MainActivity` I am subscribing each user to a topic with this method.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("latest_events").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
               // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully subscribed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

I have also installed `firebase functions` for my backend and deployed my javascript code.

**index.js**

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref("/Users").onWrite(event => {

    var payload = {
        notification: {
            title: "A new user has been added!",
            body: "Click to see"

        }
    };

    if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
        if (event.data.previous.numChildren() < event.data.numChildren()) {
            return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("latest_events", payload);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    if (!event.data.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("latest_events", payload);

});
```

I have not been getting the desired notification when a user gets added. Can't seem to get what am doing wrong.

**Firebase Functions Log Cat**

```
sendNotification
TypeError: Cannot read property 'previous' of undefined at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:15:19) at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23) at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20) at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:730:24 at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using syntax from the beta version of the Cloud Functions for Firebase. Since it was updated to 1.0 the syntax changed, and you will need to update your code to match as described in the [upgrade documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database).

Applying that to your code leads to something like this:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref("/Users").onWrite((change, context) => {

    var payload = {
        notification: {
            title: "A new user has been added!",
            body: "Click to see"

        }
    };

    if (change.before.exists()) {
        if (change.before.numChildren() < change.after.numChildren()) {
            return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("latest_events", payload);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    if (!change.after.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("latest_events", payload);

});
```

The changes are that:

- There are two parameters passed into the function, where previously there was only one.
- You no longer need to pass configuration into `initializeApp`.
- The `before` and `after` snapshots are now available from `change`.

Also see these questions (which are easy to find by [searching for the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=Cannot+read+property+previous+of+undefined+at+exports.sendNotification):

- [Firebase functions: cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647170/firebase-functions-cannot-read-property-user-id-of-undefined)
- [Firebase TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746905/firebase-typeerror-cannot-read-property-val-of-undefined)
- [Firebase Notifications using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49717034/firebase-notifications-using-node-js)